# Generate all possible well ordered string permutations

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, password-generator

I was asked this question at a job interview. I have been thinking about it yet couldn't find a solution.

Here is the problem:
You know that a password is consisted of only letters and well ordered which means that characters in the password are in alphabetical order.

For example, a 4 digit password can be "abxz" or "aBkZ" but not "aAxz" or "baxz".

Write a function that generates all valid passwords given its length. Do not forget that it must generate all the possible combinations with upper and lower characters. Ex: "aBcd", "Abcd", "abcd", "AbCd" are all different valid passwords.

I think the algorithm must be recursive. However, nothing has worked so far. I've tried the following.

```
def func(number, start_letter ='A',  match = ''):
    if number == 0:
        print(match)
    else:
        for i in range(ord(start_letter), 70):
            func(number-1, chr(ord(start_letter)+1),match + chr(i))
```

Please, save me from my misery.

Edit:
I won't approve the solution using the itertool. I think other solution is less language dependent and can be written easily in other languages.

Comment: @ggorlen This is where the English word "not" makes perfect sense :-)

Comment: Characters are in alphabetical order.

Comment: Why "aAxz" doesn't qualify? It's in ⍺betical order...

Comment: Must be that duplicate letters are disallowed.

Comment: Technically that is right but that's the rule...

Comment: You said alpha-numeric  but accepted a solution using only alphabetic. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion works great here. Pick a starting letter and only iterate from remaining letters, recursing on both upper and lower case and bumping the start letter up along the way. The base case is when the length of the string we're building is the same as the target length.

```
def all_alphabetical_pw(length, start=65, pw=""):
    if len(pw) == length:
        yield pw
    else:
        for i in range(start, 91):
            yield from all_alphabetical_pw(length, i + 1, pw + chr(i))
            yield from all_alphabetical_pw(length, i + 1, pw + chr(i).lower())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pws = list(all_alphabetical_pw(4))
    print(len(pws), "\n")

    for pw in pws[:10]: 
        print(pw)

    print("...")

    for pw in pws[-10:]: 
        print(pw)
```

Output:

```
239200

ABCD
ABCd
ABCE
ABCe
ABCF
ABCf
ABCG
ABCg
ABCH
ABCh
...
WxyZ
Wxyz
wXYZ
wXYz
wXyZ
wXyz
wxYZ
wxYz
wxyZ
wxyz
```

Comment: [Heap Overflow's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59691107/6243352) is way better, but I'll leave this up to show the intuition for writing it by hand.

Comment: This actually should run in constant time with relation to the length, since the alphabet size is a given. If length > alphabet size/2 (i.e. 26), then there are no possible solutions, and your code will stop recursing as soon as the range of the for loop becomes range(91,91). So the time complexity is a function of the alphabet size, which is constant, not the length, which is variable.

Comment: That makes sense, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools`, finds the same 239200 strings as @ggorlen's.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import combinations, product

def all_alphabetical_pw(length):
    for c in combinations(ascii_uppercase, length):
        for p in product(*zip(c, map(str.lower, c))):
            yield ''.join(p)
```

And a variation, not sure which one I like better:

```
def all_alphabetical_pw(length):
    for c in combinations(zip(ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase), length):
        for p in product(*c):
            yield ''.join(p)
```

Both work by producing *combinations* like `(('D', 'd'), ('I', 'i'), ('N', 'n'), ('O', 'o'))` and then their *products*, giving tuples like `('D', 'i', 'n', 'O')` which just need joining. The two solutions differ only by when I turn letters like `'D'` into pairs like `('D', 'd')`.

The first version does it *after* producing combinations like `('D', 'I', 'N', 'O')`, turning each such combination into a combination of (upper,lower) pairs.

The second version does it *before* producing combinations, instead building pairs for the entire alphabet once. That's more efficient, and it looks cleaner. Ok, I prefer this one now.

Benchmarks:

```
@ggorlen's  0.199 seconds
my first    0.094 seconds
my second   0.072 seconds
```

Measured like this:

```
timeit(lambda: list(all_alphabetical_pw(4)), number=100) / 100
```

Oh, one more. Takes 0.056 seconds so it's fastest, but I like it less:

```
def all_alphabetical_pw(length):
    for c in combinations(zip(ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase), length):
        yield from map(''.join, product(*c))
```

Comment: I spent a couple of hours coming up with my own solution, but it isn't as elegant as yours. Very nice indeed.